# Weird css width issue?

Tags: css, html, width

Or i have been building web pages for too long without a break or something really weird happened.

```
<div style="background-color:#0F0; margin:5px; height:5px;"></div>
```

Will result in a long bar of 5 height across the width of the parent div. This should normally not be visible since i gave the div no width.

I tried everything, messed up my whole CSS layout and nothing seemed to get rid of it. I even check some divs of me in that same project that still work like this.

So i opened a new project and just filled in that line above to make sure there wasn't some style setting messing things up. But still there is a green bar showing.

I just want my div to be the size of the text in it.

Again, i could be seeing things but this happened all of a sudden and i'm really clueless...

Comment: Code first, explanation later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline` because a div element automatic get the `display:block`

Answer (score 1):

Your div must have `display:block` either in your code or inherited from your browser.

change it to `display:inline` for your desired outcome.

Example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/Hn2xP/1

Comment: This did the trick on the example, but i never had to do that just befor this happend? I hope it works in my project as well.

Comment: your probally thinking of a "span" element, which by default has "display:inline"

Comment: @MennoGouw and welcome to SO, dont forget to accept an answer :)

Comment: No i almost never use spans... this is so weird. I'll add some extra code showing what i normally do and works soon.

Comment: its been this way my whole career, almost 10 years

Answer (score 1):

### Break the document flow

By default, `div` element has it's style `display` property set to `block`, what makes it's width to fill the dimensions of parent.

You have two options to make it clip to text, `position: absolute` or `float: left` (right works also, depends), as in:

```
<div style="background-color:#0F0; margin:5px; height:5px; position: absolute;"></div>
```

or:

```
<div style="background-color:#0F0; margin:5px; height:5px; float: left;"></div>
```

For more information, see [CSS Floats](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) and/or [CSS Positions](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

P.S. Bear in mind, that absolute position and/or floated element will remove it from document flow.

---

### span instead of div (display: inline)

If you want to keep the document flow, use `span` instead of `div` - it's `display` property is `inline` by default, as Blowsie suggested.

```
<span style="background-color:#0F0; margin:5px; height:5px;"></span>
```

---

### display: inline-block

There is also an option with `display` property set to `inline-block`, but it's compatibility is limited. See [CSS Display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property information for more details.

```
<div style="background-color:#0F0; margin:5px; height:5px; display: inline-block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a padding issue.  Difficult to diagnose without seeing code or example of site error.

try:

```
div {padding: 0px;}
```

in your css

Comment: this, imo is incorrect , its clearly a display:block / display:inline issue

Answer (score 0):

By default, the width of a div is auto, meaning that it will fill the entire available content. To have "no width" as you seem to want, set the width to zero explicitly. Or, use one of the other answers...